# Why is it necessary for an object to have a bigger size than the wavelength of light in order for us to see it?(with all of the math and physics)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

First stop. Do not mark as duplicate. I want this to be answered with every single detail of maths and physics. This rule was frequently used in Leonard Susskind's quantum mechanics lectures. I want to know the essence and the physics behind this rule.

Comment: It actually need only be half the wavelength; efforts to derive the result should watch for that. However, an "order of" result may have been all his lectures needed.

Comment: You can 'see' single color centers. The size of the defect is much smaller than the wavelength of the light they emit. Now, you cannot _image_ the defect center with that wavelength, although NSOM techniques will get you closer than a classic optical system.

Comment: As Jon Custer pointed out, you need to make "see" more precise to get a true statement (and even "possible to image" quantitatively precise for a provable one). In fact I don't see how a more elementary counterexample to the most naive interpretation of the question can't be just an electron, which appears pointlike when considered as a particle.

Comment: It's diffraction limited except when you can use some techniques to enhance. But you're looking for the diffraction limited resolution. You can look up all the math you want, why ask somebody to copy/paste or reinvent something well known? See the basics at Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system. I expect you won't get much of an answer with your demand.